# "Center of someone's universe"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is meant by *center of someone's universe*?

I read this sentence:

> Her young son is **the center of her universe**.

But I couldn't figure out the meaning.

Comment: The main person in her life.

Comment: The most important part of her life (Webster).

Comment: why is the question put on hold?

Comment: Please read the notice carefully. It says **Basic questions on spelling, meaning or pronunciation are off-topic** because they can be answered by using a dictionary. Did you look up the words  [**universe**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/universe) and [**centre/center**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/center) before asking your question? If you had, but still didn't understand what the phrase "centre of someone's universe" meant, then you should have explained that in your question.

Comment: Would looking up *center* and *universe* help?  It seems like the key here is understanding the metaphor in this common English phrase, not looking up the individual words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, a "metaphoric" usage such as ***his universe*** refers to *the universe as perceived by him* (that's to say, everything he's aware of and/or cares about).

By convention and implication (both metaphorically and according to Einstein's Theory of Relativity), *every* individual is "at the centre" of their own universe. So it's just piling one more metaphoric allusion on top to say that something *other* than one's own self is at the centre of one's universe.

In short, *He is the centre of her universe* means she thinks he is the most important thing in existence. A more "folksy / biological" (as opposed to "material / scientific") expression would be [*He is the apple of her eye.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275777/)

Answer (score 3):

This usually means a person or a thing that they care about a lot, even more than anything else. If someone is the center of my universe they mean a lot to me. I think about them all the time, want to spend time with them, and focus a lot of my time and efforts on them.

This is a metaphor! That means you're comparing two things without using the words "like" or "as". In this case, you compared a person to the universe. You can also compare other things, like a really tall thing to a tree. "The chair was like a tree, towering above the table."